# Discrepancy between theory and real life: spool and mass system connected via pulley

Tags: homework-and-exercises, forces, mass-energy, home-experiment

[image: Question]

I was given this problem in physics class. My teacher said that they reached the ground at the same time, but when I [tested it out (video)](https://photos.app.goo.gl/g4k3pJic4eDZeuJc7), I got drastically different results. I showed the professor and asked him why real life and theory did not match up, and he said to just accept it and would not explain what is going on in real life.

Why is the experimental result so different from the theoretical answer?

Comment: It's really hard to tell.  It could be all kinds of things.  It could be that there's too much friction between the rope and the pulley (because you're not allowing the pulley to rotate): this is different than the problem because the pulley is allowed to rotate freely without friction.  It also could be that the masses of the knife and the spool (in your demonstration) are significantly different, whereas in the problem they have to be the *same*.  There could be other possibilities, too....

Comment: ...Maybe you're accidentally holding the string (it's hard to tell from your video): I'm surprised that the knife didn't move *at all*, which makes me thing the string is somehow attached somewhere.   I will say that we have done this experiment in our labs, and it works pretty well, although it's difficult to get it to work exactly right, because any wobble introduced into the unspooling string messes things up (the wobble is *another* possible source of the problem).

Comment: The mass of the knife+chopstick and yoyo are both 2.5g

Comment: Then the primary issue is likely the large friction between the rope and the cylinder.

Comment: Would the friction between the rope and the cylinder cause such a drastic change in what happens?

Comment: Yes, I *think* that *any* amount of friction is going to have a drastic effect. In the frictionless case, the tension forces on either side of the string are equal, meaning once a *little* friction is introduced, the tension forces will be slightly unequal, but not enough to beat static friction between cylinder and string. Thus, the string stays stationary, and the knife therefore can't move while the spool unspools. I'm not sure about this, so I can't write an answer until I think about it more. However, the question is interesting!

Comment: in any case, it is not the same problem, you are unwinding string on one side only. The other side has no spool..

Comment: How is it not the same problem? There is a mass of B(knife) which does not rotate, and A rotates(yoyo), and they are connected together.